# center align a resizing, absolute div

Tags: html, css, position, center, expand

I have a page set up however I am having trouble aligning the news articles to the center of the page.

Here is a link to what I have so far -

http://casb1.cloudapp.net/1016/1be61016ff9a717aa34c2adf7c5aa79e/3D%20Design/news%20articles/news.html

Basically I need the red area to always be the same distance from the edges, even when it expands. Is this possible?

The red container has the css of position:absolute

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

PS. this is only my first week of learning css and html so please forgive me if it is something simple.

Thanks

Comment: Why are you using position:absolute?

Comment: To my limited knowledge, it is the only way to automatically extend the width of a div when its children 'grow'.

Comment: And why are you using iframes? Except if you're displaying content from other sites, don't do that. It's inefficient, slow and causes problems in both CSS and JS.

Comment: ohh ok. The linked pages are part of my site but since they are auto resizing i just could not get rid of the scroll bars when they were embedded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you don't need the `position:absolute` you can delete this property and add this:

```
.collection {
   display:table;
   margin:auto;
}
```

Comment: That's it. An example: http://goetter.fr/lab/divers/flexibletab/

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot that can be impoved, but going to your question, I'd do something like this:

```
.collection {
    position: static;
    display: inline-block;
}
.roundcont {
    text-align: center;
}
```

You basically need to remove the position: absolute; attribute from your .collection element and change its display to inline or inline-block and then set text-align center; to its parent div so now it looks centered.